# Why hasn't Trusty received the updates for OpenSSL's CVE-2016-2108 and CVE-2016-2107?

Tags: updates, security, openssl

OpenSSL released [a security advisory](https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv/20160503.txt), warning users of two recently discovered vulnerabilities:

- Memory corruption in the ASN.1 encoder (CVE-2016-2108)
- Padding oracle in AES-NI CBC MAC check (CVE-2016-2107)

Their recommendation is as follows:

> OpenSSL 1.0.2 users should upgrade to 1.0.2h
>   OpenSSL 1.0.1 users should upgrade to 1.0.1t

However, the latest version available for Trusty (14.04) is `1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.19`. How come such an old version is still being provided and how do I mitigate this?

Comment: As can be seen from the CVE tracker: https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2016/CVE-2016-2108.html, https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2016/CVE-2016-2107.htm; fixes have been released.

Comment: @muru The question you linked to is more generic and deals with finding out whether a package has been updated or not. This one approaches the issue from the perspective of someone who doesn't think the package _has_ been updated yet, even if the CVE tracker claims it has. OpenSSL is also a bit of a special case here since the package in the archives is often several releases behind upstream.

Comment: So, do we go about making a post for every CVE that affects OpenSSL? Better to redirect people to the USN and the CVE tracker.

Comment: @muru it may be better to convert this into a generic question for OpenSSL then. I'm not _really_ opposed to having questions for specific issues with OpenSSL since they are infrequent and tend to cause a lot of concern. Having specific CVEs in the body (or even title) increases the chances that someone will land here from Google.

Comment: Sure. I'm just wondering if we'll end up [implementing a CVE tracker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenspun%27s_tenth_rule) here. (I'm not all that certain of the infrequency of OpenSSL vulnerabilities.)

Comment: @muru remember, this question isn't "AAAH OPENSSL IS VULNERABLE - WHAT TO DO!!?!1" but rather it is "OpenSSL doesn't _appear_ to be updated - why?".

Comment: @muru 's second link doesn't work because missing l at the end. https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2016/CVE-2016-2107.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The current version does indeed include the mitigations for these vulnerabilities. Rather than keeping up with the OpenSSL releases, the security team prefers to backport fixes.

You can confirm that the package contains the mitigation for the CVEs listed in the question by downloading the Debian packaging for the `openssl` package:

```
apt-get source openssl
```

You will find a file named `openssl_1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.19.debian.tar.gz` in the current directory. Extract the contents and list the contents of `debian/patches`:

```
$ ls debian/patches
...
CVE-2016-2107.patch
CVE-2016-2108-1.patch
CVE-2016-2108-2.patch
...
```

Comment: After applying this update, Qualys SSL Labs still reports that my server is vulnerable to CVE-2016-2107.  Does the application itself (nginx, in this case) have an effect on whether the vulnerability is mitigated?

Comment: @Elkvis did you restart nginx after applying the update?

Comment: Yes.  The machine itself has been restarted a number of times since the update.  dpkg -s openssl shows that openssl_1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.19 is installed.  Same with libssl.

Comment: I am having the same issue, @Elkvis. Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: @GregDubicki No, I never did.  I gave up on it.

Comment: I resolved it by updating the following packages apart from ```openssl``` itself: ```libssl-dev libssl-doc libssl1.0.0``` and restarting nginx then. I am not sure which packaged helped and don't have time to check that now, but my problem is solved, @Elkvis .